# getting windows file description through cmd

Tags: windows-7

How do i get the File description from a Windows process using command prompt??

Comment: Please explain what you mean with "file description".

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
WMIC /OUTPUT:C:\ProcessList.txt PROCESS GET Description
```

[other parameters for Process GET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Windows XP Home does not have `wmic`. Is there another way?